# Better precision to solve a geometric progression

Tags: fortran

Letting `a1` be the first term, `r` be the constant that each term is multiplied by to get the next term and `n` be the number of terms, the geometric progression is: `ai = a1*r**(i-1)`, `pn` the product of the `n` terms and `sn` the sum of the `n` terms.

I have the formulas to calculate this, but Fortran 95 (Plato2) doesn't admit the precision I need. (For example: I can't get -1.234E+00567890 as result).

How can I "amply" the double precision to work with this "huge" numbers?

Comment: You must show your code and describe which command give the result you show. Don't forget to show how you initialize your variables. Otherwise your question will be closed as off-topic. Read [ask]  and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Such high numbers (your example -1.234E+00567890) are too large for any intrinsic numerical type supplied by Fortran standard. They are also larger than numbers used in physical and engineering applications. For example, my gfortran supports these types:

```
huge(1.0_real32)    3.40282347E+38
huge(1.0_real64)    1.7976931348623157E+308
huge(1.0_real128)   1.18973149535723176508575932662800702E+4932
```

As far as I know there is no Fortran compiler available with much larger intrinsic floating point types.

For specialized purposes, as yours, specialized libraries are needed. This site is not for software recommendations so I will not recommend any particular one. Have a look at a list of some of them at http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/mpdist/ and of course there are more around (the GNU Scientific Library will have something I am sure).